# Making Button text partially bold doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make text inside Button partially bold but this doesn't work.
I have my text placed in string values. String styling is completely ignored and text appeared as "normal" style inside button.

```
<string name="gps_yes_button_text"><b>Yes, </b>confirm this location!</string>
```

Button:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/gps_confirm_button"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/gps_button_width"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/gps_button_height"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:elevation="@dimen/gps_button_elevation"
   android:text="@string/gps_yes_button_text"
   android:textColor="@color/colorText"
   android:textSize="@dimen/gps_text_large"
   android:textAllCaps="false"
   android:background="@drawable/gps_rounded_button"/>
```

Comment: Try this `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            button.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.app_name),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        }else {
            button.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.app_name)));
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to set the button text by coding as below.

```
String buttonText = "<b>Yes, </b>confirm this location!"; 
button.setText(Html.fromHtml(buttonText));
```